# How can I get future date month and year by inputting opening date and duration month using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

**when I select date and input month duration then other field will display the target date**

how can I implement this,Please anybody help me to do that.my form is that

```js
// I have tried to do that
$("#duration").keyup(function(){
  var duration = $(this).val();
  var open_date = $("#openDate").val();
  // i want to use same function and method
  // here will next code
 var targetDate = new Date(open_date);
 targetDate.setMonth(targetDate.getMonth() + duration);
 var dd = targetDate.getDate();
 var mm = targetDate.getMonth() + 1;
 var yyyy = targetDate.getFullYear();
 var dateString = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
 $('#targetDate').val(dateString);
   // i have do that but do not get my espect out put
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Open Date :
<input type="date" id="openDate"><br><br>
Duration Month:
<input type="text" id="duration" placeholder="mm"><br><br>
Target Date :
<input type="text" id="targetDate" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
```

Comment: might be useful https://markhneedham.com/blog/2009/01/07/javascript-add-a-month-to-a-date/

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```js
$("#duration").keyup(function(){
  var duration = $(this).val();
  var open_date = $("#openDate").val();
  // i want to use same function and method
  // here will next code
 var targetDate = new Date(open_date);
 targetDate.setMonth(targetDate.getMonth() + parseInt(duration));
 var dd = targetDate.getDate();
 var mm = targetDate.getMonth() + 1;
 var yyyy = targetDate.getFullYear();
 var dateString = dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yyyy;
 $('#targetDate').val(dateString);
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   Open Date :
<input type="date" id="openDate"><br><br>
Duration Month:
<input type="text" id="duration" placeholder="mm"><br><br>
Target Date :
<input type="text" id="targetDate" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy">
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't particularly helpful. A good answer should include why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Entering 2018-01-31 for open date, and 1 for duration month, the result is 3/3/2018. Is that expected? The date in `new Date(open_date)` will be be treated as UTC, but the date string is formed using local date methods. Test this within the local offset of midnight.

Comment: partially agree with u. need to give description. but one thing, if the input is 31-Jan-2018 then what will be the expected answer?

Comment: I don't know. Should 31 Jan + 1 month + 1month give the same date as 31 Jan + 2 months? These are questions for the OP to answer.